# How to revoke the privileges of a user in OAuth using php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

A user can detach a social identity to his account. Once a provider is detached, the user won’t be able to login with it again, he need to re-attach it to login with it.

Comment: I don't know if you can revoke single permissions but you could invalidate/remove the whole token and force the user to reauthenticate.

Comment: How can i do this in php?

Comment: I didn't look at the php code google provides but it'll store the tokens somewhere. Just find the right token and delete it.